# In F# interactive, how to get the results of [<fun:Invoke@3233>] from List.map?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Total newbie F# question.

In Visual studio 2019, F# interactive file, I have:

```
open System

module Visit =
    type Model =
        {
            Id: int
            Name: string
        }

    let init col cel =
        { 
            Id = col*100 + cel*10 + 1
            Name = sprintf "My Name is col: %d  cel: %d"  col cel       
        }

    let getName m = m.Name

module Cell =
    type Model =
        {
            Id: int
            Visit: Visit.Model
        }

    let init col cel =
        { 
            Id = col*10 + cel
            Visit = Visit.init col cel
        }

    let getVisit (m:Model) = Visit.getName m.Visit
        


module Column =
    type Model =
        {
            Id: int
            Appointments: Cell.Model list
        }

    let init =
        {   Id = 0
            Appointments = [0 .. 3] |> List.map (Cell.init 0)  }

    let findAppointment m =
         m.Appointments |> List.map ( fun cell -> Cell.getVisit)
        // m.Appointments |> List.map ( fun cell -> printfn "%A" cell; cell.Id) 
       

    let find =
        init |> findAppointment
```

I get:

**val find : (Cell.Model -> string) list =
[fun:Invoke@3233; fun:Invoke@3233; fun:Invoke@3233;
fun:Invoke@3233]**

How do I get the actual Name (string) function results in a list (not [fun:Invoke@...),... ]???

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is, that `Cell.getVisit` is not applied to the cell, i.e. it should be

```ml
m.Appointments |> List.map (fun cell -> Cell.getVisit cell)
```

or

```ml
m.Appointments |> List.map Cell.getVisit
```